# Is there a way to persist options() in a R workspace image?

Tags: r

I notice that when I restart my R session all the `options()` that I set are lost.

Is there a way to make the options persist across sessions? Preferably in the workspace since I want those options to be per project and not global.

```
options(myoption=1)
getOption("myoption") # 1
a <- 42
## close & save workspace
## start R again
getOption("myoption") # NULL, options not restored
a # 42, so workspace was restored but not the options
```

Comment: Read about `?Startup`, `.Rprofile`, and [RStudio Projects](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-Projects)

Comment: @zx8754 Read about them, no direct information on how to achieve this. `.Rprofile` can be used to set `options()` but it's not the same as keeping `options()` restored automatically. (You need to keep the file updated manually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that there is no way to do this from the R console itself.

You have to put an `options(optioname=optionvalue)`  in the project's `.Rprofile` file. In RStudio, this file is sourced automatically when the project is opened as documented in  [Using Projects](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-Projects).

The `.Rprofile` file needs to be created at the same level as the `projectname.Rproj` file.

In my case the file I created `~/mytestproject/.Rprofile` contains:

```
options(myoption=1)
message("\n *** Loaded mytestproject .Rprofile ***\n")
```

It's a little inconvenient since you **need to manually to keep this file in sync** with the actual `options()`.